# C# How can i detect EvenHandler subscription in Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, roslynator

I'm writing a custom analyzer rule using Roslyn.

I want to find a method which is a handler for some event (via subscription).
Like this:

```
public class Counter
{
    public event EventHandler ThresholdReached;
}

public class TestEvent
{
    public TestEvent()
    {
        Counter с = new Counter();
        с.ThresholdReached += OnThresholdReached;
    }

    private void OnThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

In my realization it looks:

```
    private static void HandleMethodDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        MethodDeclarationSyntax methodDeclaration = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
        if (methodDeclaration.Identifier.IsMissing)
        {
            return;
        }

        IMethodSymbol methodSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(methodDeclaration);

    }
```

I don't know how to detect that **OnThresholdReached** is subscription of Event **ThresholdReached**. If someone knows how to do it, please help=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an analyzer, you cannot know only from looking at a `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, whether that method is converted to a delegate or not. Because of that, you can not know (only from looking at a `MethodDeclarationSyntax`) whether that delegate is passed to the add accessor of an event or not.

First of all, remember that a Roslyn analyzer can only see usages in the current assembly (project). If your method is converted to a delegate in another assembly, there is no way for the analyzer to see this.

Secondly, remember that

```
с.ThresholdReached += OnThresholdReached;
```

may be expressed as

```
EventHandler handler = OnThresholdReached;
с.ThresholdReached += handler;
```

If you only want to detect the first case, you can look at `AssignmentExpressionSyntax` instances of kind `SyntaxKind.AddAssignmentExpression`, and analyze those.

If you want to detect all cases where a method group is converted to a delegate, you need to look at all instances of type `SimpleNameSyntax` and analyze those as follows:

```
void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var node = context.Node as SimpleNameSyntax;

    // we're only interested in delegates
    var type = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(node, context.CancellationToken).ConvertedType;

    if (type == null || type.TypeKind != TypeKind.Delegate)
    {
        return;
    }

    // we're only interested in methods from the current assembly
    var symbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node, context.CancellationToken).Symbol;

    if (symbol == null ||
        symbol.Kind != SymbolKind.Method ||
        !symbol.ContainingAssembly.Equals(context.SemanticModel.Compilation.Assembly))
    {
        return;
    }

    // now you know symbol is a method in the same assembly, that is converted to a delegate
}
```

To find the source code for that method, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362532/1403794.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try to use this!

Comment: Hello, It works! Partually, but i have some problems. When i trying to throw a ReportDiagnostic with the location of methodSymbol (not the node of his delegate), i have nothing. I have no idea, why =(. But, if i throw a  ReportDiagnostic with location of delegate node, it works.  Maybe it's a Roslyn feature ? Maybe i shouldn't a Report Diagnostic with another node location (different from registered)?

Comment: @ДмитрийК Ask a new question for that one