# C# regex search for += operator inside a specific function

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to regex search for += operator matches inside a function named OnDisabled() in Rider (JetBrains).

Regex I have so far: `/OnDisable \(.*?\) \{(?=.*?)[^{}]+\}/gm` but it matches everything inside the curly brackets right now.

Example code I have for testing is as follows:

```
private void OnEnable () {
  someEvent.OnEventRaised += MyFunction; // Ignored
  someOtherEvent.OnEventRaised += MyFunction2; // Ignored
  anotherEvent.OnEventRaised += MyFunction3; // Ignored
}

private void OnDisable () {
  someEvent.OnEventRaised += MyFunction; // <-- Should be found #1
  someOtherEvent.OnEventRaised -= MyFunction2; // Ignored
  anotherEvent.OnEventRaised += MyFunction3; // <-- Should also be found #2
}
```

Additional information:

1. Function/code style is always `OnDisable () {`
2. Indentation can vary inside the function
3. Only want to find any `+=` operator inside the function, rest is not important

Comment: Regex is not a suitable tool for this task. It's not trivial finding out where the method ends. Using `[^{}]+` will have false-negatives (imagine having something like `var arr = new[] { 1 };` in the body of the method) and even writing something for matching balanced curly brackets will struggle with curly brackets inside strings. You should probably write a parser instead.

Comment: Parsing C# using a Regex will in general not work. It is already difficult to find the end of the method (counting braces). string literals and comments will make it impossible.

Comment: If you want to look for these things in your own code, it may be easier to do it with [Roslyn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/) instead - the parsing and analysis layer of the C# compiler, which can be used as a library. [Here's an example for how to look for event handler subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324943/c-sharp-how-can-i-detect-evenhandler-subscription-in-roslyn) (ie what `+=` represents).