# How to get SyntaxNode "MethodDeclarationSyntax" from Semantic "Method"?

Tags: c#, roslyn

## Syntax model and Semantic model communication

I have an **"InvocationExpressionSyntax"** *"invocation"* , from which i want to access **"MethodDeclarationSyntax"**.

Don't want just to compare their names, because the method parameters may differ.

By using semantic model I got access to **Operation** of invocation. By operation I have an access to TargetMethod. I would like to get **MethodDeclarationSyntax** of that method.

```
var operation = (IInvocationOperation) semanticModel.GetOperation(invocation);
var methodInvoked = operation.TargetMethod;
```

Comment: Do you really want the declaration syntax? Or do you want know the parameters?

Comment: I needed to know the declaration syntax to examine method body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```cs
private static SyntaxNode GetDeclarationSyntaxNode(InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationSyntax, SemanticModel semanticModel)
{
    var methodSymbol = (IMethodSymbol) semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationSyntax).Symbol;
    var syntaxReference = methodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.FirstOrDefault();

    return syntaxReference?.GetSyntax();
}
```

There is detailed explanation [Roslyn Get Method Declaration from InvocationExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361709/roslyn-get-method-declaration-from-invocationexpression?answertab=active#tab-top)

Edit:
include null-conditional operator to code

Comment: great, it's just what i needed. I apologize for a duplicate

Comment: Your code expects that `methodSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences` might be empty and the invokes `syntaxReference` without accounting for it.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote null-conditonal operator to example code