# C# roslyn code analysis: how to identify type definition source code?

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I parse a syntax tree to find method return type.

Now how to identify the source class definition of the type?

I need a sort of "go to definition" sample code.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then you can use `SemanticModel`'s `GetTypeInfo` , check if it is a `INamedTypeSymbol` and use it's `Locations` property.

Comment: This is somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361709/roslyn-get-method-declaration-from-invocationexpression/45362532#45362532